# nvidia drivers not working with other kernel

Tags: nvidia

When installing any kernel other than the standard one, the drivers do not work, installed it through the Application Center

EOS 6 Gtx 850m ASUS g550 driver 460,470

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is the same case, but I had to install `linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` (I already had `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` installed) in order to have my Broadcom wifi driver `bcmwl-kernel-source` automatically reinstalled for each new kernel update.

Before that, `bcmwl-kernel-source` was installed only with 5.4.x kernel.

Maybe I'm way off, but it's safe to try.

Comment: I already have these packages installed